# Creating random PCB ID via manufacturing process

Tags: pcb, manufacturing

I often purchase prototype PCBAs on the order of five to twenty pieces and need to uniquely identify them sans software.  I usually just whip out a permanent marker and label `SN 00`, `SN 01`, and so on.  But how could I design a board to have (pseudo?-)randomly-generated IDs visible to the naked eye?

An example I thought of was something like a glob of solder paste in the middle of a bunch of exposed-copper 'fingers', such that when the solder paste melts it wicks and bridges into 'random' paths.  Any other ideas or suggestions?

[image: Blob and fingers]

Comment: Are you wanting your PCB fab to somehow have these IDs already included on the boards? Or are you talking about doing this manually later? And if the latter, why not a sticker or laser engraving or the like?

Comment: I'm afraid to say that the randomness of the wicking will not be very random, and with the small differences, as the solder will tend to wick towards the area that is hotter. That means that if there is an area of the board that has less copper and components, that area will heat up sooner, and most likely wick most of the copper. Just my 2c

Comment: I think your solder paste idea would just teach you about how predictable solder can really be.  If it matters, get a roll of serial number stickers and at whatever step seems reasonable to you, put a serial number on.  For me, that would probably be the point where I took them out of the reflow oven and visually inspected them -- if they looked good, the sticker would go on.

Comment: Some PCB fabs will actually allow you to include a serial number somewhere in the silk screen

Comment: Look at id chips, there are I2C options etc. Or processors often have some.

Comment: @MadHatter I'm looking for something visual -- not software-based.